# endpoint is not routing

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I have deployed a api to our company dmz. It works as expected using the server I can use postman to hit it and all is working as expected . example GET http://server01:1979/api/v1/Controller

our infrastructure team has set up cloudflare for site https://api.external.com to point to server01:1979 and cert we set up on the local IIS.
We tested if we put a index.html file under wwwroot it worked https://api.external.com/index.html
But when i try to call my api https://api.external.com/api/v1/Controller
I get from cludflare "{"type":"https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4","title":"Not Found","status":404,"traceId":"|bf848d07129c784e983904c3edde3c92.955923eb_"}"

I am running it inProcess so No Kestrel

am running asp.net core 2.2 here is the web.config details

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Alexandria.API.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

Comment: Dumb question, but did you remove the `index.html` file afterwards?

Comment: yes why? does that affect anything

Comment: Because most web servers are set up to respond with index.html as a default document. When it's in `wwwroot`, it's available at the document root, so requests for the document root return index.html automatically. Your routes don't physically exist, so they are sent through a handler that subsumes the document root and maps anything after it internally to determine what response to send. Having an index.html can interrupt the handler, if it takes precedence on the web server in question.

Comment: It might not be the issue, but I'd remove it to verify one way or the other.

Comment: Is the API subdomain orange clouded or gray clouded? If orange clouded (i.e. proxied through Cloudflare), port 1979 will not work unless you're on Enterprise Plan and using Cloudflare Spectrum. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, there were two things working against each other. First problem was Postman here at the office. Since the company proxy's all connections I had to go into settings and turn off SSL certificate verification. 2 problem is that the only Endpoint that allows a GET request without any additional headers was not working properly through the new endpoint. once i fixed both problems all was working as expected